# qemu - two clients (tap0 & tap1) via br0 can't ping eachother but server pings ok

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm, qemu, ping

I've got:

- A host system running Ubuntu with KVM (functional)
- Two clients, one Ubuntu and one Windows 7, nothing fancy.

I've also setup (see below) a bridge via br0 for the clients:

- br0: 192.168.2.1 (with DHCP running)
- eth0 -> br0
- tap0 -> br0
- tap1 -> br0

br0 can give IP to the clients, they get:

- Windows 7: 192.168.2.29
- Ubuntu: 192.168.2.30

### Here's my problem:

- Windows ICMP -> br0: Works
- Ubuntu ICMP -> br0: Works
- Ubuntu ICMP -> Windows: Fails

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5C1VvJezouI

---

I played around with some NAT (which I'm getting the hang of via iptables) and that works like a charm! Without any issues both the clients can ping www.google.se and fetch data etc, but not between each other?!

---

Here's the commands I'm running from the beginning to end:

```
tc qdisc del dev wlan0 root 2>/dev/null
tc qdisc del dev wlan0 ingress 2>/dev/null
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F PREROUTING
iptables -t nat -F OUTPUT
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
ip route flush table main
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j CONNMARK --restore-mark

modprobe ifb numifbs=1
modprobe ip_conntrack
modprobe xt_mark
modprobe iptable_nat

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-arptables
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables

ifconfig br0 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev br0
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0

kpartx -av win7.img
kpartx -av ubuntu.img

tunctl -u `whoami` -t tap0
ip link set tap0 up
brctl addif br0 tap0

tunctl -u `whoami` -t tap1
ip link set tap1 up
brctl addif br0 tap1

kvm -no-reboot -m 1300 -hda /dev/mapper/loop0p1 -boot order=c -net nic,macaddr="DE:AD:BE:EF:EC:B6" -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=/etc/qemu-dummy

kvm -no-reboot -m 1300 -hda /dev/mapper/loop1p1 -boot order=c -net nic,macaddr="DE:AD:BE:EF:EC:B7" -net tap,ifname=tap1,script=/etc/qemu-dummy
```

At this point, I'm trying to ping between the clients without success, so I close down the systems and run:

```
brctl delif br0 tap0
brctl delif br0 tap1
ifconfig tap0 down
ifconfig tap1 down
tunctl -d tap0
tunctl -d tap1
kpartx -dv win7.img
kpartx -dv ubuntu.img
```

Comment: Do you really need to pass the traffic through the netfilter module of the host? How about just letting the bridge doing the forwarding (being a "switch")?

Comment: I plan on using the netfilter for shaping/shuffling traffic around and experiment around with some stuff, but even with bridge-nf-call* and without all the iptable/tc stuff it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't the windows firewall block pings by default? Have you tried tcpdump/wireshark on the br0, tap0, tap1? And in the VMs themselves?

Comment: Yes it does, but Ubuntu doesn't so the argument here that the firewall is causing the issue is not the fact, sorry to say. It's a routing issue from tap0 -> br0 -> tap1 from what i can tell, and i don't think wireshark on the hosts would give me anything but as a last resort i'll consider it. Perhaps on the br0 interface or even better the tap interfaces to see what's popping out of those.

Comment: Do `tap0` and `tap1` have an IP in the **host** system?

Comment: Humm nope, they don't.
Being a network tech this might be the most retarded question i'll ever ask.. but should they?
I mean they're just a virtual link patched into the virtual client, and since the KVM host can ping the KVM client and vice verse i thought that the tap didn't need to have an IP on its own?

Comment: @Torxed well, I really don't understand the routing in this case well enough, but I would expect the host kernel might be eating the packets somewhere between the guests. How about running `tcpdump` or `iptraf` on all devices on host (`tapX`, `br0` and `eth0`) and in the guest(s) at the same time? That way you'd get some idea where the packets are getting lost.

Comment: @torxed no, neither `tap1` nor `tap2` need an ip address. Can you try to enable net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians, i.e. `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians=1` and see if you get any messages in your log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
brctl delif br0 tap0
brctl delif br0 tap1

kvm -no-reboot -m 1300 -hda /dev/mapper/loop0p1 -boot order=c -net nic,macaddr="DE:AD:BE:EF:EC:B6" -net bridge,br=br0
kvm -no-reboot -m 1300 -hda /dev/mapper/loop1p1 -boot order=c -net nic,macaddr="DE:AD:BE:EF:EC:B7" -net bridge,br=br0
```

In your current scenario tap is being used.
If all VM's should be able to reach other VM's as well as virtualisation host letting br0 act as a switch is a option.

Another way would be to use [macvtap in bridge mode](http://virt.kernelnewbies.org/MacVTap) or even using [openvswitch](http://openvswitch.org/).

Comment: It works so i'll give you the solution.
However @gertcdijk also made a point which made me research my config.. i had totally destroyed the bridging functionality with "ghost" tc rules and IP table rules which i hadn't flushed/cleared properly. But your solution works.