# forward virtual interface network in KVM guest to the physical interface in the host machine

Tags: networking, ip, route

I am trying to experiment with Linux IP routes. This is what I have so far.

I have a host machine whose network details are as below.

```
wlan0     inet addr:192.168.1.9  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

- I created a guest OS in KVM and I have configured the guest network
  as **forwarding to physical device NAT wlan0**.
- So all the traffic from guest OS goes through my physical interface
  of the machine `wlan0`.
- My guest OS network details are as below.

  ```
  ens3      inet addr:192.168.104.167  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
  ```

Now, I am trying to create a virtual network interface. I did it as below.

```
tunctl -t eth4
ifconfig eth4 192.168.104.169
```

Now I plan to use `eth4` interface on my guest OS as the default interface and wish to forward all my traffic from that virtual network interface on to my `ens3` interface which in turn goes to `wlan0`.

How can I accomplish this type of forwarding?

Comment: useful reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/179508/kvm-bridged-network-not-working & this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58908/qemu-two-clients-tap0-tap1-via-br0-cant-ping-eachother-but-server-pings-o